# C# Entity Framework not picking up changes on a SQLite database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a C# Windows service that uses a SQLite database using Microsoft Entity framework. This is how I setup the SQLlite database:

```
 var services = new ServiceCollection();
 services.AddDbContext<ServicesDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite($"Filename={fileName}"));
```

I have a problem though... if I add a row on a table using an external SQLite client I immediately see the new row from the C# service. If I change a field on an existing row I don't see the new value: I need to restart the service in order to do it. Any other external SQLite client is picking up the change.

What could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: So is this a web based app? If so add `AddTransientDbContext` to inject a new DbContext for each request.

Comment: It is not  a web based app. It's a headless windows service

Comment: IoC - inversion of control. PK - primary key. Once an entities is retrieved the DbContext tracks that entity. if you requery the dB and it retrieves the same entity the existing entity already being tracked will be used so its state is not refreshed.

Comment: ok, how can I force a refresh? I changed a satellite field not the primary key, but the C# service must be aware of this change

Comment: Still you should probably re-resolve the DbContext on each external incoming request instead of keeping a single one in memory. There are various ways to do this like per ownership.

Comment: I need to reload the entity from the .db file. How can I do that?

Comment: See [Introduction to Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). Use either transient or scoped.